# Polymer: Can i change paper-drawer-panels content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer, paper-elements

Hello I want to ask if is possible to change paper drawer panels content if I use another button to open the drawer. I just need this to make the page which drawer will change content from some adjustment to do. I have the adjustments I have the to do but how to create this content changing?

This is the drawer panel I have now:

```
<paper-drawer-panel class="indexz" id="paperDrawerPanel" force-narrow right-drawer>
    <div drawer>
        <h2 style="text-align:center ">Adjustments</h2>
        <div class="togglebtn">
            Display search box<paper-toggle-button tabindex="0" id="searchcheck" name="searchcheck" class="red searchcheck"
                                                   onChange="resetradio(this)"></paper-toggle-button>

            <div class="buttons">

                <label for="label3" class="text">Choose search engine</label>
                <paper-radio-group allow-empty-selection aria-labelledby="label3">
                    <paper-radio-button name="google" id="search" class="search" value="https://www.google.com/search"
                                        onclick="formaction(this);setcheckbox()"><label for="search">Google</label>
                    </paper-radio-button>
                    <paper-radio-button name="seznam" id="search" class="search" value="https://search.seznam.cz/"
                                        onclick="formaction(this);setcheckbox()"><label for="search">Seznam</label>
                    </paper-radio-button>
                    <paper-radio-button name="bing" id="search" class="search" value="https://www.bing.com/search"
                                        onclick="formaction(this);setcheckbox()"><label for="search">Bing</label>
                    </paper-radio-button>
                </paper-radio-group>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="togglebtn2">
            <paper-toggle-button tabindex="0" id="clock" name="showclock" class="red clockdis"
                                 onChange="resetclock(this);">
                Clock
                hide/show
            </paper-toggle-button>
            <div class="buttons2">
                <label for="label3" class="text">Choose Format</label>
                <paper-radio-group allow-empty-selection aria-labelledby="label3">
                    <paper-radio-button value="24" name="format" class="format"
                                        onChange="setclock();setFormat(this.value)">
                        24 Hours
                    </paper-radio-button>
                    <paper-radio-button value="12" name="format" class="format"
                                        onChange="setclock();setFormat(this.value);setpos()">12 Hours
                    </paper-radio-button>

                </paper-radio-group>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="closebtn">
            <paper-button tabindex="0" icon="close" class="cls" paper-drawer-toggle>Close drawer</paper-button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div main>
        <div>

            <paper-icon-button icon="settings" class="drawerbtn" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>

        </div>
    </div>
</paper-drawer-panel>
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you can use a `<template is="dom-if" if=""></template>`, or the `hidden` attribute to change the content of the drawer with a data-binded properties.

The drawer will look something like this

```
<paper-drawer-panel class="indexz" id="paperDrawerPanel" force-narrow right-drawer>
    <div hidden$=[[typeTwo]]>
        ...
    </div>
    <div hidden$=[[!typeTwo]]>
        ...
    </div>
</paper-drawer-panel>
```

or for the `dom-if` version

```
<paper-drawer-panel class="indexz" id="paperDrawerPanel" force-narrow right-drawer>
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[typeTwo]]">
        ...
    </template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[!typeTwo]]">
        ...
    </template>
</paper-drawer-panel>
```

You then just have to switch the `typeTwo` property from `false` to `true` or the other way before openning the drawer to change it's content. Here it will change the whole content, but you can do the same with some sub-elements.

You can have a function per button wich will do it.

Comment: Thank you, and this I have to put to my HTML file?

Comment: For it to work, it should be in a polymer component, or if you are in your main html file, in a dom-bind. You can find the doc for dom-bind here https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-bind. If it's still not clear on how to implement it, post your whole html page, and i'll do a plunker from it :)